# Getting Error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I have a general comprehension issue with classes and objects. What I'm trying to do is pretty simple but I'm getting errors. In the code example below, sometimes the line "Call tables.MethodInCTables" runs fine and sometimes it produces error 91, object not set. IN all cases, I can "see" the method in the type ahead so I know that the code recognizes the "tables" instance and "sees" MethodInCTables. But then I get the run-time error.

```
Sub MainSub() 
Dim tables as New CTables 
Call tables.MethodInCTables 
End Sub
```

----Class Module = CTables

```
Sub MethodInCTables()
 ...do something 
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an object in MethodInCTables that needs to be initialized?

Comment: Doug: I think that the right direction. I assumed that the error referred to the "tables.MethodInCTables" line but it probably refers to the method being called. I commented out line by line in that method and found a line that made the error go away. So that would confirm that the error indeed refers to the method, however, the commented-out line uses and object that (appears to) have been declared/initialized properly. I'll keep working on it!

Comment: This is a good example of why you should post your entire code and not just the piece you assume is causing the error.  If we could see the code maybe we could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialise the CTables type:

```
Sub MainSub()
    Dim tables As New CTables 
    Call tables.MethodInCTables
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Sub MainSub()
    Dim tables As CTables
    Set tables = New CTables
    Call tables.MethodInCTables
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, I did initialize as well as declare. Code should have read as below. Even with the new keyword, I'm still getting the error. Sub MainSub()
Dim tables as New CTables
Call tables.MethodInCTables
End Sub

----Class Module = CTables
Sub MethodInCTables()
...do something
End Sub

Comment: I edited the original post to reflect your comment here.  I had a little trouble :) - hope I got it right.