# Error 91 - Object Not Set

Tags: excel, vba

This is a continuation of posting [#12772920](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772920/getting-error-91) pertaining to error 91. Okay, here's the situation.
(1) If this line is commented out, then (2) produces error 91. If not commented out, the code runs fine. 
(3) This should point the public obj shCompanies to the "Companies" sheet, shouldn't it? I'm confused why this line doesn't seem to set the shCompanies object the way that (1) does.

```
Option Explicit
Public wbCode As Workbook

Public Sub Main()
   Dim tables As New CTables
   Set wbCode = ThisWorkbook
   Call SetExcelObjects
   (2)Call tables.Indexing
End Sub

Public Sub SetExcelObjects()
   Dim tables As New CTables
   (3)Set tables.shCompanies = wbCode.Worksheets("Companies")   
End Sub


---Class Module CTables
Option Explicit
Public shCompanies As Worksheet

Public Sub Indexing()
   Dim rng As Long
   Dim tables As New CTables
   (1)Set tables.shCompanies = wbCode.Worksheets("Companies")
   rng = tables.shCompanies.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `tables` as a public instance of `CTables`.  Then you can act on it from different modules.  Re-declaring it as you've been doing "wipes the slate clean" and causes the errors you are seeing.  You certainly don't want to declare an instance of tables inside of `CTables`.

Note that best practice is to separate the instantiating tables from its declaration, therefor the line `Set tables = New CTables` in `Main`.

The below compiles and runs for me.  I think it does what you expect:

```
Public wbCode As Workbook
Public tables As New CTables

Public Sub Main()
Set tables = New CTables
Set wbCode = ThisWorkbook
Call SetExcelObjects
Call tables.Indexing 
End Sub

Public Sub SetExcelObjects()
Set tables.shCompanies = wbCode.Worksheets("Companies")
End Sub

    'Class CTables
Public shCompanies As Worksheet

Public Sub Indexing()
   Dim rng As Long
   rng = shCompanies.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Doug: I was going to try a public instance next... Here's where I'm still confused: As you point out, I'm creating two instances of CTables -- in Main() and in Indexing(). But both of these are private-scope variables even though they're both called 'table'. I'm not clear how the second use of 'table' in Indexing() is a re-declare and replaces the first use in Main(). Aren't the two 'table' variables separate and distinct?

Comment: Yes they are separate and distinct.  Your original code was failing because the table object inside `SetExcelObjects` is local to that subroutine and only exists inside of it.  It in no way affects the `tables` instance declared in `Main`.  The table instance in `Main` never has its `shCompanies` property set.  So, when you call `TableIndexing` from main it fails.  I hope that helps.  You should do some reading on the scope of variables in general, and the scope of class instances in particular.